# Laravel cron on Digitalocean

Tags: php, laravel, cron, digital-ocean

I have set up Laravel scheduler to run my custom commands at specific time. Now I wanted to set up cron on Digitalocean server to trigger `schedule:run` each minute to check if something is scheduled at the given time.

After initial SSH-ing to server, I have run `crontab -e` and added the following line to it:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/Laravel artisan schedule:run >> laravel_cron.log
```

but the problem I'm facing is that I don't see anything written in `laravel_cron.log`, but it does get created, so now I have no idea whether my commands will actually be ran.

To test it out, I have tried entering `php /var/www/Laravel artisan` but I get no output in command line.

If I change the route to say `xyz/www/Laravel` it is saying that it can't find it, so I guess the route is set up fine. Also when I manually go to the Laravel folder and run `php artisan` without the route in the middle, I get the standard output.

Comment: what happens when you run `php artisan schedule:run` in the project folder? does that work?

Comment: `* * * * * php /var/www/Laravel artisan schedule:run >> laravel_cron.log 2>&1`, note the `2>&1` part. That will write the error messages into that `laravel_cron.log` file as well.

Comment: check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators/159514#159514) for more info

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command `php /path/ artisan schedule:run` does not return any output.

If you want to log the output of a task, you can use `sendOutputTo` or `emailOutputTo`

e.g.

```
$schedule->command('foo')
         ->daily()
         ->sendOutputTo($filePath)
         ->emailOutputTo('foo@example.com');
```

More examples can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#task-output)

Comment: That also doesn't do anything, I even tried specifying in cron `MAILTO` property but nothing gets back. Does something specific need to be enabled in order to run crons on DigitalOcean?

Comment: as long as you are running linux, you don't need to do anything special to run cronjobs; that is, crons wil run as tasked. As what user are you logged in when typring `crontab -e`, does that user have rights to execute php in the laravel directory?

Comment: Well, it is a root user, I suppose I shouldn't have to set anything. Besides, command is creating actual file I set with `>>` and also I can run the command as same user when I get in the actual folder

Comment: perhaps obvious, but the `at specific time` has already happened? or you did try setting the task at every minute? can you add more information to the question about how you registered the tasks, as well as (part of) the task itself?